# 'System.NotSupportedException' web api from Windows Phone 8

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8

I'm calling a local asp.net web api method from a WP8 app, and getting the exception:

asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Can anyone help with this?

```
  public void GetProducts()
    {
        UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(baseUri + "productapi");
        fullUri.Query = "";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri.Uri);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        RequestUpdateState requestState = new RequestUpdateState();
        requestState.AsyncRequest = request;

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleProductsResponse),
            requestState);
    }

    private void HandleProductsResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // get the state information
        RequestUpdateState requestState = (RequestUpdateState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)requestState.AsyncRequest;

        // end the async request
        requestState.AsyncResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

        Stream streamResult;        
        // get the stream containing the response from the async call
        streamResult = requestState.AsyncResponse.GetResponseStream();
        ObservableCollection<Product> productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

    }
```

Comment: Probably not, because you give absolutely no indication where the exception is thrown.  Catch it, call ToString on it, and [edit] it into your quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I did it a different way anyway.

```
   public async void GetProducts()
    {
        UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(baseUri + "productapi");
        fullUri.Query = "";

        HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
        c.BaseAddress = fullUri.Uri;
        var response = await c.GetAsync(c.BaseAddress, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Product));
            String str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic[] Objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object[]>(str);
            Products.Clear();
            foreach (dynamic ob in Objects)
            {
              //do something
            }              
        }
    }
```

thanks for your help